# Box-API gives 401 in python but not with cURL

Tags: python, curl, box-api

`curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0 -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"`

This works and returns exactly what I would expect it to.

```
request = urllib2.Request("https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0")
request.addheaders = [("Authorization: BoxAuth", "api_key="+apikey+"&auth_token="+auth_token)]
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

This does not and returns a 401 error. (PYTHON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
request.add_header("Authorization", "BoxAuth api_key="+apikey+"&auth_token="+auth_token)
```

Comment: thanks for the help, that didn't fix it but I did  `headers = {'Authorization' : 'BoxAuth api_key='+apikey+'&auth_token='+auth_token,}
 request = urllib2.Request("https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0", None, headers)` and that worked for me

Comment: Python will add colon between them. :)